# Why does the clojure repl show that a var is associated with a symbol, after it's been unmapped?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I create a variable, `x`, in a Clojure namespace, store the associated var in another variable (`y`),  and then unmap `x`:

```clj
(ns user)
(def x 0) 
(def y (var x))
(ns-unmap 'user 'x)
```

If I evaluate `y` in the REPL, it prints `#'user/x`, even though the symbol `user/x` is not associated with this variable anymore.

```
user=> y
#'user/x
user=> (deref y)
0
user=> (deref #'user/x)
Syntax error compiling var at (REPL:0:0).
Unable to resolve var: user/x in this context
```

Things get really confusing if I create a new variable associated with the symbol `x`:

```clj
(def x 1)
(def z (var x))
```

Now, the repl prints both `y` and `z` as `#'user/x`, even though those variables point to different var objects:

```
user=> y
#'user/x
user=> (deref y)
0
user=> z
#'user/x
user=> (deref z)
1
user=> (= z y)
false
```

Why does the REPL print `#'user/x` when evaluating `y` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To think properly about this, you need to understand how vars and namespaces work in Clojure.

- A var is a mutable storage location, optionally named by a namespaced symbol.
- A namespace is a map from symbol to var.
- If namespace `n` has a definition named `s`, then it maps the symbol `n/s` to a var that is named by `n/s`.

So, you defined `x`, yielding a var (call it `v`) labeled `user/x` and containing 0, and stored in the namespace `user`. Then you removed that mapping from the `user` namespace. But the var `v` still exists, and still knows it's called `user/x`. So you can still look at it by traversing through `y`, which has of course saved the actual var object, and no longer cares what namespace was used to look up the var. You can, e.g. print its name and dereference it to see the value 0 that was locked in there.

You later define a new var named `x` in the `user` namespace, yielding a new var that knows it's referred to by `user/x`. But it's a distinct var, so they can hold different values, and the `user` namespace now points to a different var than the one you stored in `y`.